# Circular declarations and circular references

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, circular-reference

I'm having trouble with this piece of code which shall evaluate numeric operations. I tried searching, but no answer seemed to be helpful.

The base class to represent an operation is:

**Operacija.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Operacija
{
protected:
    char* naziv;
    int drugiO;
    Operacija* suprotna;
public:
    Operacija* retOp() { return this->suprotna; }
    int retD() { return this->drugiO; }
    void printOp()
    {
        cout << "Ime operacije: " << this->naziv << endl;
        cout << "Drugi operand: " << this->drugiO << endl;
        cout << "Ime suprotne operacije: " << this->suprotna->naziv << endl;
    }
    virtual int DoOperation(int op1, int op2) = 0;
};
```

This derived class is for multiplication:

**Mnozenje.h:**

```
//this is .h for 1st class
#pragma once
#include "Operacija.h"
#include "Deljenje.h"

class Mnozenje : public Operacija
{
public:
    Mnozenje(int b);
    int DoOperation(int op1, int op2);
};
```

**Mnozenje.cpp:**

```
#include "Deljenje.h"
#include "Mnozenje.h"
class Deljenje;
Mnozenje::Mnozenje(int b)
{
    Deljenje* a = new Deljenje(b);
    naziv = "Mnozenje";
    suprotna = a;
    if (b == 0)
    {
        cout << "operand ne sme biti 0, stoga je stavljen na ";
        cout << "default tj. postavljen na vrednost 1!" << endl;
        drugiO = 1;
    }
    else
        drugiO = b;
}

int Mnozenje::DoOperation(int op1, int op2)
{
    int a = 0;
    a = op1 * op2;
    return a;
}
```

And this derived class is for division:

**Deljenje.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "Operacija.h"
#include "Mnozenje.h"


class Deljenje : public Operacija
{
public:
    Deljenje(int a);
    int DoOperation(int op1, int op2);
};
```

**Deljenje.cpp:**

```
#include "Deljenje.h"
#include "Mnozenje.h"
class Mnozenje;  

Deljenje::Deljenje(int a)
{
    Mnozenje* b = new Mnozenje(a);
    naziv = "Deljenje";
    suprotna = b;
    if (a == 0)
    {
        cout << "operand ne sme biti 0, stoga je stavljen na default tj.     postavljen na vrednost 1!" << endl;
        drugiO = 1;
    }
    else
        drugiO = a;
}

int Deljenje::DoOperation(int op1, int op2)
{
    int a = 0;
    a = op1 / op2;
    return a;
}
```

I do understand why this does not work, and I did try with just declaring pointers instead of initialising `suprotna` member for `Mnozenje` and `Deljenje`. But I have another class being a container of an array of type `Operacija` and I can't have uninitialised pointers, because I need to call some other function using `suprotna`.

Comment: _"Im in such a hurry, my exam is in 10-12 hours."_ Well, StackOverflow isn't meant as the last resort to get you through your exam! Also have a look at this possible duplicate for your question please:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c

Comment: I just pointed that out to justify any unclearness and so on, this is a question just like any other. Thanks for tip! :)

Comment: It's a low quality question judged by SO's policies though. No matter how urgent it seems from your point of view to get it answered. StackOverflow is for setting up a long term valid Q&A format, and not to serve as your personal help-desk!

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?

Comment: @UmashankarDas firstly thank you for your time. What does not work is that i have another function that is a container for objects 'Operacija' which is a stack, so i need to create that stack and then call 'DoOperation' func for elements of that stack, and then i have func undo in that same class and i need to call it, heres its implementation
     'void Kalkulator::Undo()
{
 this->acc = this->niz[this->brel-1]->retOp()->DoOperation(this->acc, this->niz[this->brel - 1]->retD());
 this->brel--;
}'
and what is not working here is that retOp() returns loose pointer,bcs i did not initialize it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems raised by your question:

- The first is about compiling errors, due to the unnecessary circular refecences.  Implementing the answer of **NO_NAME** completely solve this topic as [demonstrated here](http://goo.gl/wzjwOx).
- The second is a segmentation fault that will occur everytime you create a `Mnozenje` or a `Deljene`:  for example, if you create a `Mnozenje` from an `int`, then you'll create right at the start of its construction a new object `Deljenje` which will create right at the start of its construction a new  `Mnozenje`, which will create ...   until a stackoverflow occurs.
- The third problem is your intended use of inheritance.  Having a container of `Operacija` instead of `Operacija*` will result in [slicing](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-slicing-in-c/) and it's doomed to fail.

**Suggestions:**

I understand that `Mnozenje` is multiplication and `Deljene` a division, and that you try to store in `suprotna`the reverse operation.

I propose you therefore to foresee a constructor with an optional argument, so that when you create a reverse operation you can indicate the original operation as reverse.

The idea would be something like this:

```
class Mnozenje : public Operacija
{
public:
    Mnozenje(int b, Operacija* rev=nullptr);
    int DoOperation(int op1, int op2);
};

Mnozenje::Mnozenje(int b, Operacija* rev)
{
    naziv = "Mnozenje";
    suprotna = rev==nullptr ? new Deljenje(b, this) : rev;   
    ...
}

// and the same kind of change for Deljenje
```

In this case, instead of recursing for ever, you create the circular reference between the related objects.

***ATTENTION:*** This work-around will make the destruction of the objects slightly more complex.  If you have enough time for your exam, consider changing the design:

- keep two pointers for the reverse operation:  one for newly allocated objects, one for pointing back to original operation.  In this case you could further improve, using `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` to help you to manage memory;
- or create a reverse operation only when it is needed (i.e. not at construction, but as result of a member function);
- or decouple in your data structure the operations from the operand;
- or avoid completely creating reverse operation by adding an `UndoOperation()` member function.

Comment: I was kidding about destructor, I now got the whole thing running smoothly, thanks to you. a simple array deletion worked.
'delete [] "var_name"'

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `#include "Mnozenje.h"` in `Deljenje.h` and `#include "Deljenje.h"` in `Mnozenje.h`. The fact that you are using a class in a `.cpp` file doesn't mean that you have to have definition of this class in a `.hpp` file.

You also don't need to write declarations of a classes like that: `class Deljenje;`, because includes (e.g. `#include "Deljenje.h"`) provides you definitions of these classes.

It seems that not quite aware of the fact how includes works.
It's pretty simple. Include just copy whole specified file to the place where is an `#include` directive. You can read more about that here: [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

Comment: this does not solve my problem ;/ but thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: @MilanMarkovicDrmr You have right. Probably the program can compile despite these flaws. I will leave this answer. It may be useful anyway.

Comment: @NO_NAME _"It may be useful anyway. "_ I doubt so, flag the question as dupe, if you think your link contains the appropriate answer please.